# Why is my script calling the python interpreter?

Tags: python

I'm very new to python debugging, so please excuse this question.

I'm stepping through some code using breakpoint() in python 3.8. And it went from one of the functions I wrote and starts executing functions in the python interpreter:

```
(Pdb++) s
--Call--
[3] > c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\objectpath\core\interpreter.py(69)execute()
[3] > c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\objectpath\core\interpreter.py(70)execute()
-> D = self.D
(Pdb++) n
[3] > c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\objectpath\core\interpreter.py(71)execute()
-> if D: self.start("Tree.execute")
(Pdb++) n
[3] > c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\objectpath\core\interpreter.py(72)execute()
-> TYPES = [str, int, float, bool, generator, chain]
```

Why is it invoking the python interpreter and calling functions from there?

Comment: can you provide some code please? From what I can see right now, I would say that it isn't invoking the interpreter, just printing the lines after `breakpoint()` is used, but if I could reproduce it myself I could give a more definitive answer.

Comment: It looks like that's how the debugger steps through lines of code.

Comment: Developmental environments like jupyter, komodo edit, PyCharm do the trick.. and see the SO 2019 year survey [here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#technology-_-most-popular-development-environments) for more IDE's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably getting confused by the `interpreter.py` file name, but that's not "the python interpreter". That's an entirely separate interpreter running on top of the Python interpreter. Your script is entering that code because it's part of a library you're using.

Your code has been running in the Python interpreter the entire time, because that's how running Python works (in the reference implementation), and it has nothing to do with this `interpreter.py`.